# Android rtsp client compiled with NDK cannot receive any UDP packets

Tags: android

I recently compiled ffmpeg and live555 for android, and built my own media client wrapper. The whole system works perfectly in all other systems (windows and linux), but not in android, just no UDP packets could be ever received. The RTSP communication works fine, which uses TCP connection. The session starts successfully, and keeps running in server. After searching for the similar topics, I see it seems that I have to acquire a multicasting permission with wifi at first. So I did:
**- put permissions in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE""/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
```

**- put following java codes in android Activity::onCreate()**

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);  
if( wm != null ) {  
    mMCLock = wm.createMulticastLock( TAG );  
    mMCLock.acquire();  
}
```

But it still doesn't work, the results are all the same in Emulator, in Galaxy S2 Phone and
in Galaxy Tab 10.1. Even I deactivate the live555 module, and just use ffmpeg ( ffmpeg has also its build-in rtsp client, but not as stable as live555, therefor, I ported live555 into android). The results are the same, rtsp ok, rtp not, where rtp uses udp as underlying carrier.

In DDMS is an error registered:
***Address Family not supported by protocol***

I think, the problem is that the UDP port is still blocked. Maybe getting multicastlock in
java is not enough for native code running in user kernel of android.

Does anyone has idea?

Steven

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

I think, in your bind you are biding to an IP, use `htonl(INADDRY_ANY)` as `s_addr`.

not sure whether this helps your cause, but it seems to solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to check it in live555 module. BTW. I now switched my client to send rtp over tcp request, then every thing works fine, just the udp request still doesn't work. An UDP connection makes much better performance for realtime media player, with TCP I have heavy packet lost in the network interface, before the packets reach the TCP stack.

Answer (score 0):

The UDP Problem in meinem RTSP client has been solved, there is nothing to do with permission and multicast lock. It is the bug inside android stl library implementation, provided in android-ndk-r7 and android-ndk-r8 both. Anyone wants to use gnu-libstdc++.so has to keep in mind: don't use string, especially string::c_str(), it leaves danger pointer in your stack, and damages everything. After I threw out every thing to do with stl, everything works fine, tcp and udp. A little off-topic: Inside the live555, there are at least 20 bugs, and the most fatal errors are: they used unblocked rtp over tcp, therefore, most packets are get lost before they reach the network interface, and at rtsp client, the rtp/tcp socket will never get the packets which are lost in the network interface, and then a rtsp session enters into endless receiving loop, it hangs.